# How to convert this jQuery code to plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, web-frontend, code-conversion

I'm trying to get the focus method (touch, mouse or keyboard) on links setting a `data-attribute`.

```
$(function() {
    var i,
        r = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

    if ("ontouchstart" in window) {
        document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {
            i = "touch";
        }, true);
    }
    else {
        document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
            i = "mouse";
        }, true);
    }
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
        i = "keyboard";
    }, true);
})
```

The problem is that I only get results writing the last part in jQuery:

```
    $("a").focus(function() {
        $(this).attr("data-focus-method", i)
    })
    $("a").blur(function() {
        $(this).removeAttr("data-focus-method")
    })
```

And I want to write the whole code in plain JavaScript. I've tried the way below:

```
    r.addEventListener("focus", function() {
        r.setAttribute("data-focus-method", i);
    });
    r.addEventListener("blur", function() {
        r.removeAttribute("data-focus-method");
    });
```

But it doesn't work.
Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Is the code here the same as your actual code?  This line appears suspect `r = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0]` when you mention "*on links*" - ie your text implies multiple/all links but your code indicates *first* link (which is a bit strange in itself).  If you actually have something like `for (var idx in document.getElementsByTagName("a")) { var r = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[idx]` then that's your problem - r will have changed by the time it hits the event listener, hence the use of `this`.

Comment: @freedomn-m the problem is that when I remove the ```[0]``` I get the "r.addEventListener is not a function" error message.

Comment: Your code [works just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/y9Lg702o/9/).

Comment: @ArthurOtaviano That's because `getElementsByTagName()` returns a nodeList which you need to iterate through and call `addEventListener` on each individual element

Comment: It's not about *removing* the `[0]` - it's more that does your real code use `[i]` (or similar)?

Comment: But looking again, it looks like you've attempted to replace `$("a")` with `document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0]` - **these are not equivalent** - the jquery version would be `$("a:first")` (or `$("a").eq(0)`) - jquery kindly wraps the collection for you and handles it all in a nice handy wrapper.

Comment: @freedomn-m it's wrong then. Sorry, I'm a beginner in JavaScript. I need to get all ```a``` elements in my page to run the focus method function.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use querySelectorAll method and use forEach to iterate the nodelist

```
document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach((link) => {
  link.addEventListener("focus", function() {
    this.setAttribute("data-focus-method", i);
  });
  link.addEventListener("blur", function() {
    this.removeAttribute("data-focus-method");
  });
});
```

Comment: Does using `setAttribute` work to set data attributes? I've always used `el.dataset` to do that.

Comment: @YaakovAinspan Yes, it does

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're trying to override the `i` on method whenever a key is pressed on the keyboard. However, I'm assuming that's the desired effect since you don't mention it in your question.

That said, here's something to get you closer to your goal of a vanilla JS version of the code.

The answer uses the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to convert the nodeList you get from `getElementsByTagName` to an array and then [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop through the array items. For each item, we add two [event listeners.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) one for `focus`, and one for `blur`.

When focused, we add the attribute. When blurred we remove the attribute. I opted for [set attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) and [remove attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute), but you can also use [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) if you want.

To determine what `i` (the method) is, I used [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

I'm still not sure why you want to override the method when a key is pressed on the keyboard so I left that. I can improve that if you let me know what the desired effect is.

```js
let i = ("ontouchstart" in window) ? "touch" : "mouse";

document.addEventListener("keydown", () => {
  i = "keyboard"
})

const links = [...document.getElementsByTagName("a")];

links.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener("focus", () => {
    link.setAttribute('data-focus-method', i);
  });
  link.addEventListener("blur", () => {
    link.removeAttribute('data-focus-method');
  })
})
```

```html
<a href="#">My link 1</a>
<a href="#">My link 2</a>
<a href="#">My link 3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution adding:

```
    var w;
    for (w = 0; w < r.length; w++) {
        r[w].addEventListener("focus", function() {
            this.setAttribute("data-focus-method", i);
        });

        r[w].addEventListener("blur", function() {
            this.removeAttribute("data-focus-method");
        });
    }
```

By the way, thanks for everyone who helped me!